# Solaris 11: Install solaris developer studio: Error

Tags: solaris, solaris-studio

I am trying to install solaris studio 12.6 in Solaris 11.4 system.
I set the publisher key and certificate as shown below:

```
 pkg set-publisher -c ./oracle/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem -k ./oracle/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem -G "*" -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release solarisstudio
```

Then sudo pkg install -–accept developerstudio-126 command gives me the blow error:

```
root@Wenge:/export/home/preethi# pkg install --accept developerstudio-126
Creating Plan (Running solver): |
pkg install: No matching version of developer/developerstudio-126 can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126@12.6-1.0.0.0
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency developer/developerstudio-126/c++@12.6-1.0.0.0 can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126/c++@12.6-1.0.0.0
             pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126/c++@12.6-1.0.0.1
    Reason:  No version for 'require' dependency on library/c++/stdcxx can be found
    ----------------------------------------
  Reject:  pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126@12.6-1.0.0.1
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency developer/developerstudio-126/c++@12.6-1.0.0.1 can be installed
root@Wenge:/export/home/preethi# pkg install --accept developerstudio-125
Creating Plan (Running solver): -
pkg install: No matching version of developer/developerstudio-125 can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-125@12.5-1.0.0.0
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency developer/developerstudio-125/cc@12.5-1.0.0.0 can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-125/cc@12.5-1.0.0.0
    Reason:  No version for 'require' dependency on developer/library/lint can be found
    ----------------------------------------
```

Solaris uname -a

```
SunOS sys1 5.11 11.4.16.4.0 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Placed key and certificate in the local system only. i've verified this command and its listing all the available packages:

```
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
developer/developerstudio-125                     12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/backend             12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/c++                 12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/cc                  12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/code-analyzer       12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/dbx                 12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/dbxtool             12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/dmake               12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/fortran             12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/c++-libs    12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/c-libs      12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/f90-libs    12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/math-libs   12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/oic-libs    12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/perflib     12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/studio-gccrt 12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
............................
...........................
```

I could see c++ available:

```
root@Wenge:/export/home/preethi# pkg list -a pkg://solarisstudio/* | grep pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126/c++
root@Wenge:/export/home/preethi# pkg list -a pkg://solarisstudio/* | grep c++
developer/developerstudio-125/c++                 12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-125/library/c++-libs    12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/developerstudio-126/c++                 12.6-1.0.0.1               ---
developer/developerstudio-126/library/c++-libs    12.6-1.0.0.1               ---
developer/solarisstudio-122/c++                   12.2-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/solarisstudio-122/library/c++-libs      12.2-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/solarisstudio-123/c++                   12.3-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/solarisstudio-123/library/c++-libs      12.3-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/solarisstudio-124/c++                   12.4-1.0.0.0               ---
developer/solarisstudio-124/library/c++-libs      12.4-1.0.0.0               ---
```

Before installing this solaris studio, any other dependent package i need to install?

Comment: `Reason:  No version for 'require' dependency on developer/library/lint can be found` - that package comes from the Solaris OS repo, not the Studio repo.  Is your `solaris` pkg publisher correctly set for the version of Solaris you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your certificate and keys expired or not registered for some reason.Try to download new keys and certificate

```
root@Solaris:~/Desktop# sudo pkg set-publisher \
> -k ~/Desktop/pkg.oracle.com.key.pem \
> -c ~/Desktop/pkg.oracle.com.certificate.pem \
> -G "*" -g https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release solarisstudio
```

Verifying publisher

```
  root@Solaris:~# pkg publisher
    PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
    solaris                     origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
    solarisstudio               origin   online F https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release/
  

 root@Solaris:~/Desktop# pkg publisher solarisstudio | grep Mirror   
    
    root@Solaris:~/Desktop# pkg list -a pkg://solarisstudio/(asterisk)
    NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
    developer/developerstudio-125 (solarisstudio)     12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
    developer/developerstudio-125/backend (solarisstudio) 12.5-1.0.0.0               ---
    ------------  snipped more than 100 lines ---------------
    
    root@Solaris:~/Desktop# pkg install --accept developerstudio-126
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Package: pkg://solarisstudio/developer/developerstudio-126/studio-legal@12.6-1.0.0.1:20170815T160721Z
    License: devpro.OTN.license
    
    You acknowledge that your use of Oracle Developer Studio is subject to the Oracle Developer Studio OTN License Agreement.  The OTN License Agreement is located at : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/studio-license-2980206.html
    
    
    
    
               Packages to install: 29
           Create boot environment: No
    Create backup boot environment: No
    
    DOWNLOAD                                PKGS         FILES    XFER (MB)   SPEED
    Completed                              29/29   11083/11083  505.6/505.6  1.7M/s
    
    PHASE                                          ITEMS
    Installing new actions                   19396/19396
    Updating package state database                 Done 
    Updating package cache                           0/0 
    Updating image state                            Done 
    Creating fast lookup database                   Done 
    Updating package cache                           2/2 
    
    
    Set Path in your profile

    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/developerstudio12.6/bin
    export MANPATH=/opt/developerstudio12.6/man
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The certificate and key are valid for 2 years. But again i downloaded the key and certificate then tried to install. Still same error.  Solaris: /etc/reelase: ```  Oracle Solaris 11.4 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                           Assembled 02 December 2019
~
```                                                                                                                                                         Will the above Solaris support developer studio12.6?

Comment: What's the output of `pkg publisher` ?

Comment: root@Wenge:/export/home/preethi# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solarisstudio               origin   online F https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release/
ha-cluster                  origin   online F https://pkg.oracle.com/ha-cluster/release/

Comment: This is [response](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4202702) from studio support engineering on OTN.Best contact support to resolve issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Have installed Solaris 11.4.20.4.0 version and i can successfully install the Developerstudio12.6.